# Is it feasible to extend Xamarin.Auth or Xamarin.Social to support native iOS 6 login with fallback to Safari?

Tags: ios6, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.auth, xamarin.social

We have an app that uses Facebook SDK for logging in.
We support **iOS 6 native login, with fallback to Facebook App and Safari.**

We're adding Twitter support soon.
We also want to implement iOS 6 login with Safari fallback for it.

Is there any code in Xamarin.Auth or Xamarin.Social that we can reuse, or do we need to write it from scratch? We need to be able to retrieve access tokens, store them and authenticate requests.

I tried writing my own authenticator for Xamarin.Auth, but its design insists I provide a view controller for authentication, whereas I need to either show iOS 6 auth dialog, or Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just open sourced [something that solves this problem for us](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7081/we-just-open-sourced-stampsy-social-a-small-library-on-top-of-xamarin-auth-social?new=1).

Answer (score 2):

`Xamarin.Auth.Authenticator` sublcasses are single methods of authentication, there's no built in fallback mechanism. You'd have to choose whether you wanted to use native or safari earlier in the process and then use the appropriate `Authenticator` for it.

`Authenticator`s provide both the means for the user to provide information (through, say, a web page using `WebRedirectAuthenticator`) and to obtain the user tokens and other information. `OAuth2Authenticator`, for example, uses `WebRedirectAuthenticator` to take you to an authorization page and then later retrieve the access tokens from the redirect.

Xamarin.Social uses `Authenticator` when you open the sharing compose page and need to authenticate and along with Xamarin.Auth uses `Authenticator` in its creation of requests to include the necessary authorization information.

Comment: But I wouldn't need an authenticator then, would I? Meaning, if Safari gives me the access token, I wouldn't need to use `Authenticator` classes, right?

Comment: I added more information to my answer to hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. So if I want to use Safari for Twitter authentication, I'd need to manually create an `Account` with `access_token` I got from Safari, save it, and then use `TwitterService` with this account, right?

Comment: You should be able to do that, yes.

Comment: If you're curious, this is what I came up with [so](https://github.com/gaearon/sociopath/blob/master/Sociopath/Social/SafariAuthenticator.cs) [far](https://github.com/gaearon/sociopath/blob/master/Sociopath/Social/SafariTwitterService.cs). Unfortunately I have to wrap authenticator because I can't change the code.

Comment: I get a 404 when I click that. I'm still not sure what you're trying to accomplish though, the existing OAuth*Authenticators are already using Safari...

Comment: I created a [pull request that adds Safari authentication support](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/pull/20). Existing authenticators don't use Safari, they use web views. The issue is, even if user is logged into Facebook/Twitter in Safari, they still have to fill login form. We noticed a lot of people don't remember their Facebook/Twitter passwords or don't want to fill another form, so Safari support is essential to us. (Of course this is a non-issue if they have filled iOS6 settings, but not everybody has.)

Comment: Oops, [that's](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/pull/21) the correct pull request.